# Updating D3.js graph on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, json, html, d3.js

I’m new to to d3 and have combined mbostock’s stacked bar graph example ( http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 ) with a map to show data (canada.json)

I would like the graph to display an updated chart on the d3.mouseover event of the province:
http://gao8a.github.io/ (something like this)

Unfortunately, I was only able to get the axises to display. It's showing either multiple or the same axis overlapping:

(These will take ~ 3 seconds to load)

Multiple:
http://bl.ocks.org/GAO8A/566e238a72e5ebd1e2c1

Same Axis overlap
http://bl.ocks.org/GAO8A/64f94bb494c4a73f2bf6

I understand I probably need a ‘mouseout’ event to delete the previous but I’m not quite sure how to design that either.

Can anyone point out what I’m doing wrong and how I should be loading the data?

PS:

I was going to make a jsfiddle but can’t seem to get it to get it to work with my hosted canada.json data.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GAO8A/GAO8A.github.io/master/canada.json

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you keep adding the axes in the `tooltip` element. Unfortunately this creates the overlaps. What you could do is add the axes once, and the readjust their domain with the new values that correspond to the element being hovered.

So in essence if you could add the following lines:

```
var X_AXIS  = tooltip.append("g").attr("class", "x axis x-axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
X_AXIS.call(xAxis)
X_AXIS.append("text").attr("dy", "3em").attr("dx", "50em").style("text-anchor", "end").text("Month");
var Y_AXIS  = tooltip.append("g").attr("class", "y axis y-axis")
Y_AXIS.call(yAxis)
Y_AXIS.append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("dy", "-3em").attr("dx", "-8em").style("text-anchor", "end").text("Temperature (Celcius)");
```

just before adding your map, this would in a sense 'initialize' the axes.

So further, in your `mouseover` handler, you could add the following lines, just after you determine your `x` and `y` domains.

```
X_AXIS.call(xAxis)
Y_AXIS.call(yAxis)
```

or better still, to add some transition:

```
X_AXIS.transition().duration(400).call(xAxis)
Y_AXIS.transition().duration(400).call(yAxis)
```

This way, you don't keep adding axes, you just readjust the ones currently intialized.

Hope this helps.